# Apply filter to all routes except two?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way I can apply a filter (specifically "auth") to all routes *except* "login" and "sessions.store"?

There's a small section on [pattern based filters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) but I don't know how to negate them.

Something like ASP.NET MVC's [AllowAnonymous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx) would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep - just use [route groups](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups) like this

**routes.php**

```
// Not logged in area
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin']);
Route::get('/session', ['as' => 'session.store', 'uses' => 'AuthController@sessionStore']);


// Logged in area
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function ()
{
     Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);
     // Rest of your routes here
}
```

Or there are some other options. You could create a [class based filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters), and do something like this (*semi pseducode, I havent tested it, but you get the idea*)

```
class AdminFilter {

      public function filter()
      {
         if ( ! ((Route::getCurrentRoute() == 'login') || Route::getCurrentRoute() == 'session.store')))
         {
             // If the route is not login or session.store, then run the auth check
             if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
         }  

         return true;
      }
 }
```

Edit: Using your request for something like AllowAnonymous - you could also do something [like this in your base Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters).

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('login', 'sessions.store')));
    }
```

Then all your controllers 'extend' the base controller. This means that all routes (that use a controller) would have the auth filter applied automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In the `app/filters.php` file, there's a filter that comes with the stock laravel that has:

```
App::before(function($request)
{

});
```

You could use this to check for your certain pages, and if all is fine then let it through, if not then redirect to login.